# Does a conjugacy class of element lying outside of a subgroup only contain elements outside of that subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have a quick (and hopefully really easy, as I suspect it is) question about conjugacy classes.

> ***Question:*** Given a (finite, for simplicity) group $G$, a subgroup $H$, and an element $g\in G\setminus H$, can the conjugacy class $\text{Cl}(g)$ contain any elements of $H$?

I suspect the answer to be "no." I have checked a few simple examples explicitly (such as $G=D_6$, $H=\mathbb{Z}_3$, and $g$ ranging over all elements of $D_6\setminus\mathbb{Z}_3$), and it seems to check out, but I've failed to come up with what I expect to be a fairly straightforward proof (assuming it's actually true that all elements must lie outside of $H$).

Supposing that $kgk^{-1}=h\in H$ for some $k\in G$ we know, of course, that $g=k^{-1}hk$, and so $k\in H$ would contradict the assumption that $g\in G\setminus H$, but I cannot see why $k\in G\setminus H$ could not happen.

Is my suspicion that one cannot have $kgk^{-1}\in H$ true? If so, why> Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at an example, where H is not normal in G.

Comment: I didn't even notice that all of the examples I happen to check were normal subgroups -- what luck! Now that you mention it, it's actually as obvious as I suspected it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a element in a subgroup can have conjugates outside it. The easiest way to see this is in a Symmetric Group - say $S_4$ - where the conjugacy classes are defined by cycle types. The element $(1 2 3)$ generates a subgroup of order $3$ which fixes the point $4$. But there are conjugates of this element which don't fix $4$ and aren't in the subgroup.

A subgroup is normal if and only if it is the union of complete conjugacy classes. So any non-normal subgroup will have conjugates outside it.

Answer (score 1):

We can even choose an example in the group you picked, $G=D_6$. Let $r$ and $s$ be the generating rotation and reflection, with $srs=r^2$. Then $s$ generates a subgroup of order $2$ $H=\{1,s\}$, and $rsr^{-1}=sr$ is not in the subgroup.